# How to open a command-line application and leave it open to accept keyboard input

Tags: perl

Is it possible to open a third-party command line through Perl, execute a few commands through it, and then leave it open to accept more commands from the keyboard?

We have 'adminclient' CLI program from Oracle. I want to execute the `connect` command through `adminclient` and then leave it to accept more manual commands.

I used,

```
open ORA, "| adminclient" or die "Can't pipe to adminclient: $!";
print ORA "connect http://xyz:9000 as oggadmin password xxxxxx\n";
print ORA "info all";
close(ORA);
```

This works, but it returns to the shell prompt once done. Here I want my `adminclient` program left open to accept more commands manually.

Comment: `print ORA <STDIN>` perhaps?  Why not just open the adminclient directly and interact with it normally?

Comment: Hi, Actually we dont want to enter long connect string everytime while work with adminclient CLI, like 'connect http//<SERVER_NAME>:<PORT> as  <USER_NAME> password <PASSWORD> .. SO want to make small auto connect script which jump directly into it..

Comment: I found system('adminclient','-hold','-e') works..means it keep adminclient CLI open..  but don't know how to pass STDIN (Atlest connect string) ?

Comment: why not just write a bash wrapper script that you call instead of adminclient

Comment: Hi, well Im not quite sure how to achieve it with bash wrapper.. I tried by simply put like as below.. but it doesn't solve my purpose..

Comment: test.sh -- exec adminclient  and in Perl script, open(MESSAGE, "| ./test.sh |") or die("adminclient failed\n");
print MESSAGE "connect http://<server_name>:9000 as oggadmin password xxxxxx\ninfo all\n";
close(MESSAGE);
It simply executed and come out to shell prompt..

Comment: No, I mean, skip the perl script, just write a bash script which starts up adminclient with the right parameters.

Comment: I tried it first.. But i soon found its not possible with  my limited knowledge of bash script..

Comment: It also not allowed me to stay at adminclient CLI, after connecting.. 
connect="connect http://<SERVER_NAME>:9000 as oggadmin password xxxxxx"
adminclient << EOF
$connect
info all
EOF

Answer (score 0):

You're most of the way to having a Perl wrapper for `adminclient`. Just add

```
print ORA $_ while <STDIN>
```

before the `close` and your Perl program will accept and pass on commands from the keyboard

Comment: Hi, I tried but it still not work.. it simply hang.. I mean it even donot show me adminclient prompt..
------------
open ORA, "| adminclient" or die "Can't pipe to adminclient: $!";
print ORA "connect http://<SERVER_NAME>:<PORT> as oggadmin password <PASSWORD>\n";
print ORA "info all";
print ORA $_ while <STDIN>;
close(ORA);
---------------

Comment: -bash-4.1$ perl call_final.pl

Oracle GoldenGate Administration Client for Oracle
Version 12.3.0.1.2 OGGCORE_12.3.0.1.0_PLATFORMS_171208.0005

Copyright (C) 1995, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Linux, x64, 64bit (optimized) on Dec  8 2017 07:43:27
Operating system character set identified as UTF-8.

Comment: It won't show the prompt, but should pass on commands that you type.

Comment: Hi, well i tried it as well.. but it wont pass commands to adminclient prompt.. whatever I type... I need to Ctrl+c to comeout from this 
^C
-bash-4.1$
OGG (not connected) 1>

Comment: OGG (not connected) 1>  ..... This is adminclient prompt...but it simply show here after existing with Ctrl+C..